# Using for loop with wildcard cmd

Tags: command-line

Inside a batch file, I am trying to write a for loop to process files in a directory. I have tried doing this:

```
for %%file in (*.in) do echo %%file
```

It tells me: `%file was unexpected at this time.`

Can someone solve my problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A loop variable cannot have more than 1 letter in its name, eg:

```
for %%f in (*.in) do echo %%f
```

Comment: Yes, that solved my problem. I never saw that rule after typing `for /?`!

Comment: "*I never saw that rule after typing `for /?`*" -  look again: "*%variable  Specifies a **single letter** replaceable parameter.*"  Also see [For](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx) on MSDN: "*{ `%variable` | `%%variable` } : Required. Represents a replaceable parameter. Use `%variable` to carry out `for` from the command prompt. Use `%%variable` to carry out the `for` command within a batch file. Variables are case-sensitive and **must be represented with an alpha value, such as %A, %B, or %C**.*"

Comment: Thanks, now I see it.

Comment: Windows 10 gives `%%f was unexpected at this time.`

Comment: @johnywhy in what context? You need to be more specific. I suggest you post this as a new question, along with an example.

Comment: @RemyLebeau This works: `for %f in (xlsm xlsb) do xcopy SourceDir\*.%f DestinationDir\ /S`

Comment: @johnywhy the documentation quoted is quite clear that `%f` is used in a `for` loop **on the command-line**,  and `%%f` is used in a `for` loop **inside a batch file**.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thx, i suspected that was the reason.